# How to express a tangent vector in local coordinates?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

I have a linear system of ODEs $x'(t)=A(t)x(t)$ that I project onto the sphere by differentiating $s=\frac x{|x|}$ to get $s'=(A(t)-sA(t)sI)s$. It is clear that the RHS is a vector tangent to the sphere, but it has as many coordinates as the original system. How can I express this vector field in a coordinate system like, for instance, spherical coordinates?
My first thought was to choose some chart $\varphi$ around a given point $p$ and start computing the partials $\partial_i f(\varphi^{-1}(x))$, but that will give me the tangent vectors in terms of derivations, and I do not know how to make the connection between derivations and the tangent plane to the sphere. Is there some general way to do this on other embedded manifolds?

Comment: I think you mean $s'(t)=(A(t)-s(t)^TA(t)s(t)I)s(t)=(A(t)-s(t)s(t)^TA(t))s(t)$.  Just use the usual identification "derivation = directional derivative = tangent vector", or use a more sensible coordinate system to mostly eliminate the work.

Comment: @user10354138 so for the embedded sphere $\Bbb S^n=M\subset \Bbb R^n$ I can take the identity map $\iota :M \to \Bbb R^n$ and compose its differential $d\iota : T_pM\to T_p\Bbb R^n$ with the isomorphism $I:T_p\Bbb R^n: v \mapsto [v(x_i)]$ and solve for the $v$ satisfying $I(d\iota(v)(f))=[v(x_i\circ \iota)]=(A(t)-s^TA(t)sI)s$?

Comment: In particular, for a given chart $(U,\varphi)$ around $p$ I can express $v(f)=v^j\partial_j(f\circ \varphi^{-1})|_{\varphi(p)}$ so I just need to solve the linear problem $v^j\partial_j(\pi_i\circ\iota\circ \varphi^{-1})|_{\varphi(p)}=[(A-\iota(p)^TA\iota(p)I)\iota(p)]_i$ which is solvable because the RHS is orthogonal to $\iota(p)$ right?